# Displaying CPU usage and FPS in an Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, frame-rate, ddms

I have set up my DDMS to work with the emulator and display the processes running etc. but in the Dev Tools of my emulator it firstly wont let me tick the Show CPU Usage box, and secondly I do not seem to have an option to display the FPS which apparently, according to sources on the internet, is possible to do.

Has anyone had this trouble and know how I can solve it and display CPU usage and FPS as my android game is running?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea of what CPU speed your emulator is emulating try this:

1) start a shell session (adb shell),

2) then run "cat /proc/cpuinfo" to get the BogoMIPS.

Here’s [more information on this](http://jars.de/english/android-emulator-performance).

Comment: Huh? That is for CPU **speed**, not usage.